# Partial derivative of function by a vector

Tags: calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, control-theory, robotics

I am struggling to understand the results of a partial derivative of a vector function with respect to a vector.

A plane has equation $\begin{bmatrix} a&b&c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ z \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} =0$ which can be written in terms of $\textbf{p}$, the position vector of the points on the plane  $\begin{bmatrix} a&b&c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{p} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} =0$.

The end effector of a manipulator has position vector $ \textbf{q} = \begin{bmatrix} x_q \\y_q \\ z_q \end{bmatrix} $. So if the end effector is to be in contact with the plane then the constraint equation is $ \Phi(\textbf{q}) = \begin{bmatrix} a&b&c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{q} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} =0$

My notes then say the corresponding velocity constraint for the end effector of the manipulator is $ \frac{\partial\Phi(\textbf{q})}{\partial\textbf{q}} = \begin{bmatrix} a&b&c\end{bmatrix} \dot{\textbf{q}}=0$. Can anyone explain where this result comes from? I cannot understand why the $\dot{\textbf{q}}$ is there.

Many thanks!

Comment: We have $D\Phi(q) = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$. It seems like they assume $q \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. What they wrote is $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(q(t)) = D\Phi(q(t))q'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}q'(t)$. I think $\dot{q} = q'$.

Comment: @Mason thanks for your response! What I'm confused about is its a derivative w.r.t q and not t

Comment: Yes their notation is strange. Check how they define  $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo and they intended to write $\frac{\partial\Phi(\textbf{q})}{\partial\textbf{q}} \dot{\textbf{q}} = \begin{bmatrix} a&b&c\end{bmatrix} \dot{\textbf{q}} = 0$?